# Can't style material-ui with its own props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, isomorphic-style-loader

I'm using the material-ui and try to style the background-color of the `RaisedButton`, using one of its props called `backgroundColor`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Home.scss';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className={s.h1}>Pomodoro Tech</h1>
                <div className={s.imgContain}>
                    <img src={require('./pom.png')} width="100%" height="100%"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="Login"
                        secondary={true}
                        backgroundColor="#77CA2D"
                    />
                    <RaisedButton
                        backgroundColor="#77CA2D"
                        label="About"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(Home, s);
```

But that property never makes any differences.

The version of the material-ui I am using is `0.15.0-alpha.1`, according to the result of `npm list --depth=0` command.

Before I ask this question I've [done some search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774004/material-ui-inline-style-not-working), but can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: My best guess is that it's caused by your CSS because when I paste in what you show minus the styles, it honors my backgroundColor specification. Another possibility is that it's a bug in 15.x. I'm using 14.x.

Comment: which version of material-ui are you using?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone according to the answer in the link that I put in my question body, I replaced the ``RaisedButton`` with the ``FlatButton`` and the ``backgroundColor`` props worked fine.However when I tried the css solution in that answer, it failed and my ``RaisedButton`` remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, have been using material-ui `v0.14.4`, may be it's been breaking in `0.15.0-alpha.1`

Please paste the working example on JSBin or somewhere to debug it further.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't include `primary={true}`; it will ignore your `backgroundColor` otherwise. See mine below:

```xml
<RaisedButton
  label={stepIndex === 2 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
  disableTouchRipple={true}
  disableFocusRipple={true}
  onClick={this.handleNext}
  backgroundColor={teal400}
/>
```