# Unable to override Material-UI theme styles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) in a project and I am trying to override the default theme style of `textTransform:"uppercase"`, and instead, replace it with `textTransform:"capitalize"`.

Consulting the docs on [custom styling](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/styles) informed me that I should use inline styles or a custom class.

Adding `className="capitalize"` (which has as a `text-transform` property in the class) or adding `style={{textTransform: "capitalize"}}` produces the same result. The parent div is passed the CSS property, but is ultimately overridden by a child `span`.

Is this [intended behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777361/1704381), or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom theme to override the textTransform:

```
const App = () => {
    const customTheme = { button: { textTransform: 'capitalize' } };

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(customTheme) }>
      <Example />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  )
};
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/88uq8751/7/

Comment: This worked marvelously for my purposes, thank you. Out of curiosity is there any way to create a change to a single button, rather than all buttons (as changing the theme file does)?

Comment: Yup. use the labelStyle property:  labelStyle={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }} on the RaisedButton or FlatButton

Answer (score 0):

Please give more info in you question.
However,I think this is not intended behaviour. I guess, check your other props, maybe with those props the effect of style props is getting overrided.

Still if that is not the cause, check the material-ui repo codebase on GitHub. From my experience working with material-ui, many problems I solved by going through their codebase and not using their doc. Hope the info helps.