# how to make rounded RaisedButton and Textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to add style to `RaisedButton`,but it doesn't work,and

```
<RaisedButton type="submit" label="Submit" style={{container:{borderRadius: "5px"}}} primary/>
```

And I also look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774004/material-ui-inline-style-not-working),and still doesn't help:

```
<RaisedButton label="raised button" className="raised-button--rounded" />
.raised-button--rounded,
.raised-button--rounded button {
  border-radius: 25px; /* assuming one is not already defined */
}
```

My expected result is like this 
[image]

I want to make a rounded textfield and button.Can anyone give me some advice to help me with this.

Any help would be great appreciate!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the properties I used to copy that button style:

```
    <RaisedButton
      label="Submit"
      buttonStyle={{ borderRadius: 25 }}
      style={{ borderRadius: 25 }}
      labelColor={'#FFFFFF'}
      backgroundColor={"#0066e8"}
    />

  label: button label
  buttonStyle: shapes the portion that has the background
  style: shapes the underlying root element
  labelColor: changes the font color to white
  backgroundColor: changes the background color to dodger-blue
```

Gif of button with properties mentioned above:

[image]

TextField:

```
    <TextField
      underlineShow={false}
      color="white"
      type={'password'}
      value={'Foo'}
      inputStyle={{color: 'white', padding: '0 25px'}}
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)', borderRadius: 25 }}
    />
```

Comment: Yeah,it works,what about Textfield?Can you give me some advice or example?

Comment: How can I do the same for Dialog ?

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi if you are looking for help with a separate issue I would suggest posting a new question.

Comment: I should try this `<Card style={{borderRadius: 25}}>`

Comment: This TextField answer doesn't work for me. Has something changed since 2017?